# IdentityServer: What is the difference between SigningCredential and DataProtection?

Tags: identityserver4

what is the difference between SigningCredential and DataProtection?
The signing credential is to sign de JWT
And the DataProtection to sign de cookies
Should I use two different certificates?

Answer (score 1):

They are unrelated and both keys should be provided and configured for production deployments.

**SigningCredentials** is all about the keys used to sign the ID and access token. It's use by IdentityServer.

The **Data Protection API** also needs a encryption key and that is mainly used to encrypt the **ClaimsPrincipal** User and also optionally the tokens if the SaveToken option is set to true.

I did a blog post about the data for some time ago: [Storing the ASP.NET Core Data Protection Key Ring in Azure Key Vault](https://www.edument.se/en/blog/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault)

If you want to peek inside the secured cookies, then I just posted a blog post about that here: https://nestenius.se/2023/11/22/exploring-what-is-inside-the-asp-net-core-cookies/